# Scrapy web scraper can not crawl link

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I'm very new to Scrapy. Here my spider to crawl twistedweb.

```
class TwistedWebSpider(BaseSpider):

    name = "twistedweb3"
    allowed_domains = ["twistedmatrix.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/",
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(),
            'parse',
            follow=True,
        ),
    )
    def parse(self, response):
        print response.url
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1]
        filename = filename or "index.html"
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

When I run  `scrapy-ctl.py crawl twistedweb3`, it fetched  only.

Getting the `index.html` content, I tried using `SgmlLinkExtractor`, it extract links as I expected but these links can not be followed.

Can you show me where I am going wrong?

Suppose I want to get css, javascript file. How do I achieve this? I mean get full website?

Comment: You haven't shown enough code here to even guess at what your problem is. I suggest you complete the fine Scrapy tutorial and then your question will either answer itself or you'll be able to explain what the problem is. http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/tutorial.html

Comment: I did follow the tutorial. I changed a little it the spider as you can see above.

Answer (score 4):

`rules` attribute belongs to `CrawlSpider`.Use `class MySpider(CrawlSpider)`.
Also, when you use `CrawlSpider` you must not override `parse` method,
instead use `parse_response` or other similar name.

Comment: Thank Rho. You save me a day.
It works after modifying as you suggested